# Investigating whether or not the sequences defined as follows does converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(\Bbb R^2,d)$ be a metric space. Let $(x_n)$ be sequences defined as follows:

1. $x_n = \left(\frac{1}{n-1}, \frac{n-2}{n-3} \right)$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$.
2. $x_n = \left(\frac{1}{n+2}, \frac{n^2+2}{n^2+1} \right)$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$.

For all $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2) \in \Bbb R^2$, given some metric $d$ in $\Bbb R^2$ defined as follows:

(a). $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$.

(b). $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=\max\{|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|\}$.

(c). $d$ is discrete metric, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) = 
\begin{cases}
1, \ &\text{if} \ (x_1,x_2) \ne (y_1,y_2), \\
0, \ &\text{if} \ (x_1,x_2) = (y_1,y_2),
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
for any $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2) \in \Bbb R^2$.

Investigate whether or not the above sequences with respect to each of the above metrics converges.

**Attempt:**
I claim that all the sequences defined above are convergent with respect to metric defined on (a) and (b), but not on (c). That is, for 1. and 2., $x_n \to x$ with $x=(0,1)$.

**Definition.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A sequence $(x_n)$ of $X$ said to be ***convergent*** to $x \in X$ if for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n \ge n_0$, we have $d(x_n,x)< \varepsilon$.

*First*, let's consider the sequence defined on 1.
For (a): Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedean Principle, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $N > 3 + \frac{2}{\varepsilon}$. Hence, for any $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n \ge N$, we have
\begin{align*}
d(x_n,x) &= d\left(\left(\frac{1}{n-1}, \frac{n-2}{n-3} \right), (0,1)\right)
= \left|\frac{1}{n-1}-0\right| + \left|\frac{n-2}{n-3}-1\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{1}{n-1}\right| + \left|\frac{1}{n-3}\right| < \frac{2}{|n-3|} \le \frac{2}{|N-3|} < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the definition above, we conclude that $x_n \to x$.

For (b): Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedean Principle, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $N > 3 + \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Hence, for any $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n \ge N$, we have
\begin{align*}
d(x_n,x) &= d\left(\left(\frac{1}{n-1}, \frac{n-2}{n-3} \right), (0,1)\right)
= \max\left\{\left|\frac{1}{n-1}-0\right|, \left|\frac{n-2}{n-3}-1\right|\right\} \\
&= \max\left\{\left|\frac{1}{n-1}\right|, \left|\frac{1}{n-3}\right|\right\} < \frac{1}{|n-3|} \le \frac{1}{|N-3|} < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the definition above, we conclude that $x_n \to x$.

For (c): Since $\frac{1}{n-1} \ne 0$ and $\frac{n-2}{n-3} \ne 1$ for any $n \in \Bbb N\setminus \{1,3\}$, then $d(x_n,x)=1$. Hence, by taking $\varepsilon_0 = 1>0$ and $n=N \in \Bbb N$, we have $d(x_n,x) \ge \varepsilon_0$. Thus, there exists $\varepsilon_0=1>0$ such that for any $N \in \Bbb N$, there exists $n=N$ for which $d(x_n,x)=1\ge \varepsilon_0$. Therefore, $x_n \nrightarrow x$, by negating the above definition.

*Second*, let's consider the sequence defined on 2.
For (a): Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedean Principle, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $N > \frac{4}{\varepsilon}$. Hence, for any $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n \ge N$, we have
\begin{align*}
d(x_n,x) &= d\left(\left(\frac{1}{n+2}, \frac{n^2+2}{n^2+1} \right) - (0,1) \right)
= \left|\frac{1}{n+2}-0\right| + \left|\frac{n^2+2}{n^2+1}-1\right| \\
&= \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n^2+1} < \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} \le \frac{2}{n} \le \frac{2}{N} < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the definition above, we conclude that $x_n \to x$.

For (b): Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. By the Archimedean Principle, there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $N > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Hence, for any $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n \ge N$, we have
\begin{align*}
d(x_n,x) &= d\left(\left(\frac{1}{n+2}, \frac{n^2+2}{n^2+1} \right) - (0,1) \right)
= \max\left\{\left|\frac{1}{n+2}-0\right| + \left|\frac{n^2+2}{n^2+1}-1\right| \right\} \\
&= \max\left\{\frac{1}{n+2}, \frac{1}{n^2+1}\right\} \le \frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{N} < \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Thus, by the definition above, we conclude that $x_n \to x$.

For (c): Since $\frac{1}{n+2} \ne 0$ and $\frac{n^2+2}{n^2+1} \ne 1$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$, then $d(x_n,x)=1$. Hence, by taking $\varepsilon_0 = 1>0$ and $n=N \in \Bbb N$, we have $d(x_n,x) \ge \varepsilon_0$. Thus, there exists $\varepsilon_0=1>0$ such that for any $N \in \Bbb N$, there exists $n=N$ for which $d(x_n,x)=1\ge \varepsilon_0$. Therefore, $x_n \nrightarrow x$, by negating the above definition.

Does the above approach correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You forgot to investigate wether $x_n$ converges to some other point than $(0,1)$ with respect to the discrete metric. Different metrics can lead sequences to converge to different points.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos For 1, where does the sequence should be converges to?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos How to investigate it?

Comment: Replace $(0,1)$ by an arbitrary point $(a,b)$, then do the same thing you already did.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Beside of the cases on discrete metric, does the proof correct?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Wait... why should I take an arbitrary point $(a,b)$?

Comment: You want to investigate wether there is some point to which the sequence converges. So either you have to find a specific point and show that the sequence converges to that point, or you have to show that *all* points are not limits of the sequence. In order to do the latter, you have to start with an arbitrary point and show that the sequence does not converge to that point.

Comment: Your proofs for convergence look fine, though. It's just the proofs for divergence which need work.